# Met-on les tirets aux nombres en lettre qui contiennent une virgule? Ex: "quatre virgule un" ou "quatre-virgule-un"?

Tags: orthographe, nombres, syntaxe, trait-d-union, réforme-orthographique-1991

En appliquant la nouvelle orthographe, c'est-à-dire de mettre les traits d'union entre tous les mots dans un nombre. La règle est-elle a même pour les nombres contenant le mot "point" et le mot"virgule"?

- "quatre virgule un" ou "quatre-virgule-un"?
- "quatre point un" ou "quatre-point-un"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En complément, la [règle](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/sites/academie-francaise.fr/files/rectifications_1990.pdf) c'est qu'« on lie par des traits d’union les numéraux formant un nombre complexe, inférieur ou supérieur à cent ». Les *[numéraux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/num%C3%A9raux) cardinaux* sont aussi appelés *noms de nombre* (TLFi). Or « virgule » (ou point) n'est pas un *nom de nombre*. On pourrait possiblement en rester là et c'est conforme à la conclusion d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50726).

Dans un [billet](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL057), l'*Académie française* dit qu'on peut « lier par un trait d’union tous les éléments qui composent le nombre, sans exception », mais elle ne donne pas d'exemple de nombre qui ne sont pas entiers. La conjonction *et* n'est pas un nom de nombre non plus, mais on a besoin de le lier avec le trait d'union dans un nombre dans certains cas pour éviter le sens d'[addition](http://www.renouvo.org/regles.php) ("quarante-et-un tiers" (41/3) ; "quarante et un tiers" (40 + 1/3)) qui correspond à un nombre décimal (40,333~). Dans un contexte où l'on devrait distinguer en lettres un nombre avec décimale d'une liste de nombres entiers séparés par virgule (étrange mais pas impossible), on peut imaginer que le trait d'union soit également utile...

Dans un [billet](https://bescherelle.ca/ecriture-des-nombres/), *Bescherelle* affirme plus simplement « la règle est donc simple pour l’emploi des traits d’union : il y en a partout dans le numéral composé désignant un **nombre entier**. » (je souligne). Donc non dans les exemples en question.

Indépendamment des rectifications, « le nombre accompagné d’un symbole du Système international d’unités doit être exprimé en chiffres » ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_n&page=9MYvIsaIGlDA.html#zz9MYvIsaIGlDA)) ; on peut aussi écrire en lettres le nombre (incluant partiellement en chiffre) et le symbole (Termium). Dans un [exemple spécialisé](http://www.cptaq.gouv.qc.ca/index.php?id=498&eID=dam_frontend_push&docID=6511) et régional basé sur l'approche classique, avec un nombre plus petit que 100 on n'a pas employé de trait d'union avec le mot virgule ; c'est purement anecdotique mais ça milite dans le sens qu'on ne veut pas considérer ce mot comme un numéral.

Finalement, des outils web sont en désaccord sur les résultats ([LeFigaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frnombre.php) ; [chiffre-en-lettre](https://www.chiffre-en-lettre.fr/)). L'expression du nombre avec « dixième » (*quatre et un dixième*) etc. permet de contourner un peu la difficulté.

Comment: Qu'est-ce que ça voudrait dire « quatre-et-un dixième » ?? Peut-on même dire ça ??

Answer (score 2):

Bonne question. Il semble que le cas ne soit jamais abordé dans les documents de référence.

Je dirais que les tirets sont requis entre tous les numéraux formant un nombre, mais vu que *virgule* ou *point* ne sont pas des numéraux, ils devraient êtres isolés par des espaces.

Il n'y a d'ailleurs pas consensus sur la manière d'écrire les nombres décimaux en toutes lettres, `4.1` sera par exemple *quatre virgule un*, *quatre point un* (rare) ou *quatre et un dixième*.

Comment: Vraiment intéressant, [lefigaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frnombre.php) et un autre [site .fr](https://www.chiffre-en-lettre.fr/) ont un outil qui donne un résulat différent pour le même nombre !

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 C'est vrai. Contrairement au Figaro, j'ai du mal à considérer la virgule comme un numéral.